# I am unable to configure Jenkins with git lab community edition (12.6.0) getting below error ,Help me to resolve

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration

**Question 1**:
i am trying to install  **Jenkins GitLab Plugin** and **Jenkins Git Plugin**.But in my Jenkins version(2.210) it won't available to download .Can anybody explain any alternative way to download this ?

**Question 2** :
I have successfully installed ruby plugin and but still getting same error ?i am configuring Jenkins with windows 10.

```
Dependency errors:
Some plugins could not be loaded due to unsatisfied dependencies. Fix these issues and restart Jenkins to restore the functionality provided by these plugins.
Gitlab Hook Plugin version 1.4.2
ruby-runtime version 0.12 is missing. To fix, install version 0.12 or later.[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Jenkins requires plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/ruby-runtime last version
And you plugin require  JRuby 1.7.18

Comment: How to do that ? via Jenkins UI ?

Comment: yes, to install plugin manage jenkins -> manage Plugin,

to install JRuby - https://www.jruby.org/2014/12/22/jruby-1-7-18.html

Comment: jruby is nowadays deprecated since January 2022 see https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2021/12/22/deprecated-ruby-runtime/ . The suggestion is to use https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin or https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-branch-source instead.